# How to write a Hello World Bootloader for MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, bootloader, osdev

I'm learning MIPS Assembly by the book [MIPS Assembly Language Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131420445), but my I've just started learning MIPS because I want to build a MIPS OS, but now as I can see, there isn't any documentation talking about boot and these things. Then I'm asking here for someone that have already done this to point me at the right place.

*I've already have developed a simple OS in x86 Assembly*

Comment: "I've already have developed a OS in x86 Assembly" - oh no you haven't, Nathan. But thanks for the laugh.

Comment: @Neil: Actually, I wouldn't be surprised if he has. Developing an OS isn't hard. Heck, most of us embedded/microcontroller programmers have had to do it at one time or another. Designing a good one is slightly harder depending on how you define "good". The hardest part is getting other people to use it.

Comment: @slebetman You obviously haven't been following Nathan's many posts here - believe me, he hasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, MIPS used a similar boot loader to the linux's loader *lilo* called [milo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILO_(boot_loader)), perhaps that is worth checking out first to see how is it done.

Good luck with your Mips OS... ;)

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Anyway, I'm going to upvote, because this can be useful for someone. **;-)**